# Transfer data from Amazon S3 to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket populated daily from Cognos. Would it be possible to import this data into marketing cloud daily (using an automation or to kick off a jounrey)?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure this just as any other scheduled data load into Marketing Cloud:

1. First, create a new file location in Marketing Cloud. Go to Administration > Data Management > File Locations, select the Amazon Simple Storage Service dropdown for Location Type.
2. Next go to Contact Builder > Data Extensions and create a new Data Extension that will be used for storing your data.
3. Then, go to Automation Studio and create a new Automation. Inside the automation configure an Import activity, for file location use the AWS bucket you defined earlier and use your Data Extension as the target.
4. Once you have the Automation configured, you can set it on a schedule. The same Automation can also be used as a Journey trigger if needed.

Here’s a video describing the process in detail: https://youtu.be/QzdK3L-b11g

Docu: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_rn_april_2021_setup_aws_s3.htm&language=en_US